# splitting the value and displaying in a formatted way

Tags: javascript, java

I am getting a json array value and parsing it and i am displaying it in a jsp page inside the textarea. To make it more readable i am splitting it by ',' and displaying it.

```
var splitStr = retrievedValue.value1
var output = splitStr.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {                                            
  document.getElementById("textarea").value += (output[i] +'\n');
}
```

so the output is like

```
{"ind":""
"ser":[{"serv":[{"cos":0.0
"max":0.0
"start":{"eve":"B"
```

but i like the output to be like

```
{"ind":""
"ser":
    [{"serv":
        [{"cos":0.0
"max":0.0
"start":
    {"eve":"B"
```

i tried splitting again by ":[" by not getting the desired output.

Comment: can you please share the string

Comment: it is pretty big so i added a few lines of it

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the format of [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)?

```js
var json = '{"ind":"","ser":[{"serv":[{"cos":0.0,"max":0.0,"start":{"eve":"B"}}]}]}';

document.getElementById('out').value = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(json), 0, 4);
```

```html
<textarea id="out", cols="40" rows="20"></textarea>
```

Comment: what does the 0,4 in the mentod stringify mean

Comment: The arguments are used as options for the method. First one for selection and second for indentation. :) Check this if you want more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: `0` is the replacer function, which is not given and `4` is the spacer, which controls the indentation of the nested objects.

Comment: I am getting the output as follows when i try ur aproach[
    "[{\"ind\":\"\"",
    "\"ser\":[{\"serv\":[{\"cos\":0.0",
    "\"maxi\":0.0",
    "\"start\":{\"eve\":\"B\"",

Comment: it could be, but in the textarea, you get the unescaped quotes. (maybe i miss something ...)